# Epic that ignores action until first request completes

Tags: rx-java, rxjs, redux-observable

A colleague and I have added a redux-observable like flow to our android application and can't figure out how to create an epic that stops receiving actions until the first call completes.

Originally I thought we could use `skipUntil()` but then realized the result of `skipUntil()` is swallowed and never passed along to the rest of the chain.

Below is some rough JS code showing what we're hoping to accomplish.

```
  const fetchUserEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType(FETCH_USER)
    .skipUntil( /* first request completes */ )
    .mergeMap(action =>
      ajax.getJSON(`/api/users/${action.payload}`)
        .map(response => fetchUserFulfilled(response))
        .takeUntil(action$.ofType(FETCH_USER_CANCELLED))
    );
```

It's almost like I need a `skipMap()` operator that acts like `switchMap()` but only honors one request at a time, while ignoring all items if an observable is ongoing.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're pretty sure that's what you need (it's usually not, dropping the input while you execute a previous query means the result is outdated, `switchMap` and/or `debounce` are usually preferred), `take(1) + repeat` should work, as the action observable is hot.

```
const fetchUserEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType(FETCH_USER)
    .take(1)
    .concatMap(action =>
      ajax.getJSON(`/api/users/${action.payload}`)
        .map(response => fetchUserFulfilled(response))
        .takeUntil(action$.ofType(FETCH_USER_CANCELLED))
    )
    .repeat()
```

Here's a snippet simulating the logic.

```js
// simulate action$.ofType(FETCH_USER) every second
const obs1 = Rx.Observable.interval(1000).publish()
obs1.connect()

function getStuff(i) {
  return Rx.Observable.timer(i*1000).mapTo(i)
}

obs1.take(1).concatMap(getStuff).repeat().subscribe(console.log)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.0.2/Rx.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll give this a try. The use case we're thinking of is when the user rapidly clicks a submit button or attempts to refresh data before the original response had a chance to return.

Comment: Maybe disabling the submit button while the request is inflight is a better/safer option (based on the state, set in FETCH_USER, reset in FETCH_FULLFILLED/CANCELLED)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to do anything fancy, there is already an operator for this called `exhaustMap`. `exhaustMap` is similar to `concatMap` except that it will silently drop requests that come in while the previous one is still processing.

```
const fetchUserEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType(FETCH_USER)
    .exhaustMap(action =>
      ajax.getJSON(`/api/users/${action.payload}`)
        .map(response => fetchUserFulfilled(response))
        .takeUntil(action$.ofType(FETCH_USER_CANCELLED))
    );
```

Comment: @jachenry exhaustMap is definitely the most idiomatic

Comment: @jayphelphs Do you know if there is an equivalent for rxjava? Doesn't show up in the docs.

Comment: @jachenry there is no equivalent. Would need a custom operator.

Comment: Sorry, when I read your original post I didn't understand that this question is actually for RxJava, because you're using the same pattern of redux-observable in a custom Java-based implementation--which btw is freaking awesome. If you ever open source it, link me!